# Geocoding to get coordinates in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding

I am using the below code to get coordinates from the address in a dataframe. but the output is the same in all the rows. What am i doing wrong here.

```
for i in dxb_df:
    address = dxb_df['Address'].replace(' ', '+')
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={}&key=KEY'.format(address)
    result = requests.get(url).json()
    dxb_df['Latitude'] = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
    dxb_df['Longitude'] = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to use the i parameter so all your HTTP requests are the same
and so you get the same results.

```
for i in dxb_df:
    address = dxb_df['Address'].replace(' ', '+')
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={}&key=KEY'.format(address)
    result = requests.get(url).json()
    dxb_df['Latitude'] = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
    dxb_df['Longitude'] = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
```